# I am not able to see cinematic wallpaper option

Tags: google-workspace, google-people-api, google-pixel

I am currently running on Android 14 beta (U1B1.230908.003) and I am not able to see cinematic wallpaper option, I have seen on multiple google insiders channeles on youtube like 9to5 Google as they get an option to convert any picture to a cinematic wallpaper but I am not able to see that from a long time Please help me with that